# streaming audio in android

Tags: android, audio-streaming

I use this code to stream an audio. But it didn't worked.

```
    public class MediaPlayerAudio extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
       OnPreparedListener, OnErrorListener {

          MediaPlayer mp;

          public v

oid onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
          Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
          bt.setOnClickListener(this);
      }



      @Override
         public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
             Log.i("radio", "prepare finished");
             mp.start();

         }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             try
              {
                  mp = new MediaPlayer();
                  mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                  mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                  mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
                  mp.setDataSource("http://stream1.tanitweb.com/rtci");
                  mp.prepareAsync();
              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                  Log.e("radio", e.getMessage());
              }

        }



        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

      }}
```

On click in the button, I have this error

```
05-15 09:31:14.360: ERROR/PlayerDriver(30): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFErrCorrupt
05-15 09:31:14.371: ERROR/MediaPlayer(330): error (1, -10)
05-15 09:31:14.371: ERROR/MediaPlayer(330): Error (1,-10)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that media format you're trying to play is not supported from android. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core) is table with all supported formats and it seems that ASF is not in it. I've tried your url and it's pointing to rtci.asf

Comment: What is the http sever that you use ?

Comment: I have the same problem and after researching i figure out that was due to the http headers. Are you setting all parameters content length, content type etc. Try to stream from some other http server.

Comment: So the  problem is not in the code. Can you give me the name of the server that you used to resolve my problem?

Comment: try to play the url http://freedownloads.last.fm/download/182052320/I%2527m%2Ba%2BPilot.mp3

Comment: I put this mp 3 in the servor. I run the code but I obtain the same error 05-15 09:31:14.360: ERROR/PlayerDriver(30): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFErrCorrupt
05-15 09:31:14.371: ERROR/MediaPlayer(330): error (1, -10)
05-15 09:31:14.371: ERROR/MediaPlayer(330): Error (1,-10)

Comment: Could you try it with a real device? Sometimes, emulators give errors even though it works fine in a device.